# Store array of arrays value in one comma separated string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have this return array

```
 $leaseArray =  Array ( [0] => Array ( [LeaseNumber] => OL/2011/0343 ) [1] => Array ( [LeaseNumber] => 184 ) [2] => Array ( [LeaseNumber] => OL/2011/0118 ) [3] => Array ( [LeaseNumber] => OL/2016/1759 ) [4] => Array ( [LeaseNumber] => OL/2013/0858 ) [5] => Array ( [LeaseNumber] => OL/2012/0535 ) [6] => Array ( [LeaseNumber] => OL/2017/2208 ) [7] => Array ( [LeaseNumber] => 2355 ) )
```

I want to save all the values of LeaseNumber in to one comma separated string
like `$string = "OL/2011/0343 , 184 , OL/2011/0118 , OL/2016/1759"`

please help me

```
$lease = array();
        for($i=0;$i<=count($leaseArray); $i++){
            $lease = $leaseArray[$i]['LeaseNumber'];
        }
```

Comment: And you have tried what so far?

Comment: i tried doing with for loop and while loop  but it doesn't  gave the expected result

Comment: Show your work then

Comment: I can do it with 1 line of code and 2 function calls, just saying....

Comment: And how did it not give the expected result

Comment: [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: @iainn - bingo.

Comment: Just curious tbh why not make a one-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a one-liner then this could work:

```
$csv = implode( ' , ', array_map( function( $a ){ return $a[ 'LeaseNumber' ]; }, $leaseArray ) );
```

expanded:

```
$csv = implode( ' , ', // step 2: implode on ' , ': space-comma-space
    array_map( // step 1: pass $lease array into array_map so that we can get a new array
        function( $a ){ return $a[ 'LeaseNumber' ]; }, // Accept each array in $a and only return the LeaseNumber. array_map will build a new array out of just these values
        $leaseArray // the array to be processed
    )
);
```

---

In essence, this is the same as:

```
$csv = implode( ' , ', array_column( $a, 'LeaseNumber' ) );
```

but `array_map()` allows you to transform the data before output/return if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a one-liner then this is the way

```
$csv = implode(' , ', array_column($a, 'LeaseNumber'));
```

As I said in the comments, 1 line, 2 function calls.

Answer (score 0):

One-liners are great but sometimes hard to read. If you want to stick with what you have here are some note

```
<?php 
$array = array(array("LeaseNumber" => "OL/2011/0343"), array("LeaseNumber"=> 184 ), array("LeaseNumber"=> "OL/2011/0118") , array("LeaseNumber"=> "OL/2016/1759"), array("LeaseNumber"=> "OL/2013/0858"), array("LeaseNumber"=> "OL/2012/0535"), array("LeaseNumber"=> "OL/2017/2208"), array("LeaseNumber"=> 2355));


$lease = array();

//Not equal to the count it starts at 1 not 0
for($i=0;$i<count($array); $i++){
    //lease is an array add to the index not overwrite
    $lease[] = $array[$i]['LeaseNumber'];
}

//You needed to finish with this
$csv = implode(", ",$lease);

echo $csv;
```

As an fyi switch to a foreach in this case makes life easier:

```
$lease = array();
foreach($array as $obj){
    $lease[] = $obj["LeaseNumber"];
}
```